# Laravel 5.1 loading relationship data into selected row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `timesheet` table and a `user` table in my database.  The following relationship is setup on the `timesheet` model.

```
/**
 * The user that owns the timesheet.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User\User');
}
```

The above means I can get user data when I select timesheets from the database by using something like:

```
$this->timesheet->whereStatus('Approved')->with('user');
```

This will load the user object in the result and if converted to an array will look like so;

```
0 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "user_id" => 2
    "week" => 1
    "year" => 2016
    "week_ending" => "Sunday 10th January 2016"
    "total_hours" => "45.00"
    "token" => "0e6796a2dc68066c8d36ff828c519af00657db02b733309b8a4ac0f7b5d6a385"
    "status" => "Approved"
    "supervisor_id" => 1
    "approved_by" => 1
    "created_at" => "2016-01-13 15:42:49"
    "updated_at" => "2016-01-14 14:52:07"
    "user" => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "first_name" => "Bill"
      "last_name" => "Andrews"
      "email" => "Bill.andrews@domain.com"
      "status" => 1
      "created_at" => "2016-01-13 15:38:18"
      "updated_at" => "2016-01-14 14:50:03"
    ]
  ]
```

However, I only need `first_name` and `last_name` from the user table.  Is there a way to merge/flatten the `user` array with the `timesheet` so that it looks like this instead;

```
0 => array:14 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "user_id" => 2
    "week" => 1
    "year" => 2016
    "week_ending" => "Sunday 10th January 2016"
    "total_hours" => "45.00"
    "token" => "0e6796a2dc68066c8d36ff828c519af00657db02b733309b8a4ac0f7b5d6a385"
    "status" => "Approved"
    "supervisor_id" => 1
    "approved_by" => 1
    "created_at" => "2016-01-13 15:42:49"
    "updated_at" => "2016-01-14 14:52:07"
    "first_name" => "Bill"
    "last_name" => "Andrews"
  ]
```

I have tried to use eager loading like so;

```
$this->timesheet->with(['user' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('first_name', 'last_name');
}])->get()->toArray();
```

However, it results in the following output;

```
array:126 [▼
  0 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "user_id" => 2
    "week" => 1
    "year" => 2016
    "week_ending" => "Sunday 10th January 2016"
    "total_hours" => "45.00"
    "token" => "0e6796a2dc68066c8d36ff828c519af00657db02b733309b8a4ac0f7b5d6a385"
    "status" => "Approved"
    "supervisor_id" => 1
    "approved_by" => 1
    "created_at" => "2016-01-13 15:42:49"
    "updated_at" => "2016-01-14 14:52:07"
    "user" => null
  ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why the user relationship is null in your second example is because in order for Eloquent relationships to work, it needs the keys that tie the relationships. In other words...

1. Get `timesheet`.
2. Get `user` with only `first_name` and `last_name`.
3. Build relationship.
4. Since you did not fetch the user's id, the `user's id` and the `timesheet's user_id` do not match so the relationship cannot be built.

In order for your query to work, you need to adjust it like this:

```
$this->timesheet->with(['user' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
}])->get()->toArray();
```

With that out of the way, if you want a flattened result, I think it's best to use `joins` rather than eager loading because of the nature of eager loading.

```
$this->timesheet
     ->join('users', 'timesheets.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
     ->select('timesheets.*', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
     ->get()->toArray();
```

This assumes that your table names are `users` and `timesheets`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is the information I was after.  I will award bounty in 9 hours (it's telling me I can't award until then).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to get a list

```
->lists('first_name', 'last_name');
```

or if you wanted to perform a select

```
->select('first_name', 'last_name')->get()
```

**Update**
You can also perform eager loading to eager load related objects. Here is an example

```
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('first_name', 'last_name');

}])->get();
```

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: If you think I have answered your question correctly, can you please mark this as the correct answer for the next guy please. Thanks !

Comment: I have tried `$rows->lists('week_ending', 'user.first_name', 'user.last_name', 'created_at', 'total_hours', 'status');` which is a list iof the columns I need, but it it just returns `"Bill" => "Sunday 10th January 2016"`

Comment: Please see above output (I have updated my original post) after eager loading.

Comment: In the eager load code that you pasted in the question I dont see anything that satisfies this ->whereStatus('Approved') statement you had in the original. Was it expected?

Comment: The `->whereStatus('Approved')` is not needed.  Each timesheet belongs to a user regardless, so the user info should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel models have a way to modify data before getting/setting an attribute. You can actually add the attributes to the model by defining a getter function. This will let you reference the user names in the same way you would the `user_id` or `status`. These functions are also great for changing date formats for a view or sanitizing form input.

```
/**
 * Get the first name of the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->first_name;
}

/**
 * Get the last name of the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->last_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what a `join` do.

[From the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins)

> The query builder may also be used to write join statements. To
>   perform a basic SQL "inner join", you may use the join method on a
>   query builder instance. The first argument passed to the join method
>   is the name of the table you need to join to, while the remaining
>   arguments specify the column constraints for the join.

```
$this->timesheet
      ->leftjoin('user', 'user.id', '=','timesheet.user_id')
      ->get()
      ->toArray();
```

If you want to be more selective on your fields, you can choose what you `select`;

```
$this->timesheet
      ->leftjoin('user', 'user.id', '=','timesheet.user_id')
      ->select('timesheet.*', 'user.first_name', 'user.last_name')
      ->get()
      ->toArray();
```

As other have suggested, it might be better to use the DB query builder such as

```
this->timesheet = DB::table('timesheet')
                 ->where('timesheet.status', 'Approved')
                 ->leftjoin('user', 'user.id', '=','timesheet.user_id')
                 ->select('timesheet.*', 'user.first_name', 'user.last_name')
                 ->get()
                 ->toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case it's better to use Raw SQL or Query builder. 
Because relations made for using database data as an relational objects.